# Sound Designer's Commentary

Tags: director, directors

In a similar format to a Director's Commentary - does anyone know of any films where the sound designer or re-recording/dubbing mixer gets a commentary to talk through what they've tried to achieve?

I think getting a list together of films that include this would be a great resource to have!

Cheers

Answer (score 4):

Cast Away has a very interesting commentary from Randy Thom.

Answer (score 3):

[SoundWorks Collection](http://soundworkscollection.com/) has got a ton of incredible videos about the sound design for various media.

Answer (score 3):

The commentary for Se7en I can highly recommend. There's a great one about sound and music on it.

Answer (score 2):

The Lord of the Rings boxed set has nearly a movie's worth of material, including sfx and score.

Comment: +1. Watching these extras was one of the main things to inspire me into getting into SD! I believe at one point they were playing elephant noises through a PA in a tunnel and recording the results!

Answer (score 1):

A Bugs Life has an isolated 5.1 SFX track as well as a documentary.

The Conversation also has commentary by Walter Murch.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that Walter Murch talks about sound design on his commentary on The Conversation in addition to discussing the picture editing.

Answer (score 0):

Spiderman 2 has a bit about how they made the scene where Doc Ock robs the bank. I don't know what edition of the DVD it is on though.

Answer (score 0):

This may sound weird, but a thought came to me.  Every film has a sound designer's commentary: the full mix.

Sound designers let the film's soundtrack speak for itself.  And that's part of the beauty, no need to explain ourselves, fully open to personal interpretation and exploration.

Answer (score 0):

Monsters Inc has an isolated 5.1 SFX track on my DVD. Nice feet foley.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to check out [soundworks collection](http://soundworkscollection.com/)

Answer (score 0):

Surprised nobody mentioned -> http://designingsound.tv/

Should cover everything you want.